# Compare current Password with Database password ASP.NET MVC with DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I compare user's `CurrentPassword` with the password stored in the database?

I want to let my current password to compare with my database password but how do I do it? The database password is encrypted by MD5.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordVM changePasswordVM, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        LeaveUser _User = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_User, changePasswordVM.CurrentPassword, changePasswordVM.ConfirmNewPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (returnUrl == null)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                else
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password Change Attempt.");
        }
        return View();
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Current Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current Password : ")]
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter New Password")]
    [MinLength(8), MaxLength(20)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New Password : ")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm Password")]
    [MinLength(8), MaxLength(20)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password does not match the confirmation password.")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm New Password : ")]
    public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: But my main question is i want to let Current Password compare with the Server side password so that the user can not key in any random password on Current password and still change the password.

Comment: Ok, I thought all you wanted to do was check that when users change their password, they shouldn't be equal to their current password. But if you want to compare `CurrentPassword` to the password in the database, then ... do nothing. The default controllers already do that. If you wrote the change password code yourself, then [edit] your question and show that code.

Comment: Have post my controller code, Currently it does not change the password. it does nothing at all.

Comment: [Remote("CheckSamePasswordAsExisting", "Validation")]
[Display(Name = "New Password : ")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }

Create controller name Validation and method called CheckSamePasswordAsExisting

usermanager.FindAsync. using username and new password entered.  if  it return null mean that password entered is not existing password.

Comment: It's not *encrypted*, but in fact **hashed** with MD5 - which means you cannot "decrypt" it, so all you can do is take the current password, hash it with MD5 as well, and then compare the hashed values.

Comment: I’m new to MVC I don’t really understand what sunnykachwala saying & marc_s I have no idea how to hash a password on asp.net..